# "Segmentation Fault" numa função que realiza Quicksort

Tags: c, classificação, quicksort

Estou fazendo um trabalho que pede para criar uma função quicksort para ordenar alfabeticamente um arquivo txt, porém ele está apresentando o erro:

> segmentation fault

Na função main eu chamo a função assim:

```
  quickSortWordsArray(vetor,0,i-1);
```

E função é esta:

```
void quickSortWordsArray(char words[],int esq,int dir){

    int i,j,pivo=esq;
    char aux[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS] = {'\0'};

    for(i=esq+1;i<=dir;i++){
        j=i;
        if((strcmp(words[j],words[pivo])<0)){
            strcpy(aux,words[j]);
            while(j>pivo){
                strcpy(aux[j],words[j-1]);
                j--;
            }
            strcpy(words[j],aux);
            pivo++;
        }
    }
    if(pivo-1 >= esq){
        quickSortWordsArray(words,esq,pivo-1);
    }
    if(pivo+1<=dir){
        quickSortWordsArray(words,pivo+1,dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: o primeiro parâmetro da sua função: `void quickSortWordsArray(char words[],int esq,int dir)`, você está pedindo uma string, mas acho que queria um vetor de strings não é? quando você faz `words[j]` está acessando um caractere e não uma string, é isso mesmo que quer? Outro ponto é o loop while, você está copiando tudo para a matriz `aux`, mas acho que na verdade deveria ser: `strcpy(words[j],words[j-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Editei o código que você tinha feito fazendo alterações nas partes que eu comentei e não recebi nenhum seg fault, os pontos errados que eu encontrei:

O primeiro parâmetro da função realmente estava incorreto, você pede uma string quando na verdade precisa de uma matriz, isso pode fazer com que em alguns casos você obtenha erros de SEGFAULT e claro que não vai ordenar corretamente nos casos em que não der erro. Os casos que geram erros são os casos em que sua string tem tamanho menor que o vetor(matriz de strings) que você pretende trabalhar, nesses casos você acaba acessando posições inválidas da string, pra falar a verdade eu nem sei como isso compilou: `strcmp(words[j], words[pivo]);`, já que `words` é uma string `words[j]` retorna um caractere e não uma string e portanto não devia ser aceito como argumento da função `strcpy`

O outro erro é a matriz `aux`, o uso dela está incorreto e também impossibilita a ordenação correta, você só precisa de uma string auxiliar, a cópia dos dados em `words` deve ser feito nele próprio e não na matriz `aux` que não está sendo usada pra nada além de auxiliar no loop de ordenação, na verdade ela pode ser apenas uma string.

aqui está o código que funcionou:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void quickSortWordsArray(char words[][20],int esq,int dir){

int i,j,pivo=esq;
char aux[20] = {'\0'};//20 é o MAX_COLUMNS

for(i=esq+1;i<=dir;i++){
    j=i;
    if((strcmp(words[j], words[pivo])<0)){
        strcpy(aux, words[j]);
        while(j>pivo){
            strcpy(words[j],words[j-1]);
            j--;
        }
        strcpy(words[j], aux);
        pivo++;
    }
}
if(pivo-1 >= esq){
    quickSortWordsArray(words,esq,pivo-1);
}
if(pivo+1<=dir){
    quickSortWordsArray(words,pivo+1,dir);
}
}

void printStrings(char strs[][20], unsigned int n) {
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    std::cout << strs[i] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
char words[][20] = {"ola", "alo", "helloWworld", "bbbbbbbbb", "aaaaaaaaaaaa", "ababababab"};

quickSortWordsArray(words, 0, 5);

printStrings(words, 6);

system("pause");

return 0;
}
```